# В Visual Studio Code шрифты выглядят как будто сжаты

Tags: ide, шрифты, visual-studio-code, редактор-текста

Visual Studio Code шрифты выглядят как будто сжаты,
переустанавливал несколько раз, менял шрифты, не помогло.
OS Ubuntu.

Меню выглядит отлично. Хотелось бы, чтобы так шрифты выглядели в самом редакторе.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: странно у меня все ок

Comment: в гитхабе попробуй отчет отправить

Comment: У меня установлен как в Ubuntu так и в Windows 10. Полет нормальный, без сбоев. Только улучшения от версии к версии.

Comment: Если запустить VS Code с параметром `--disable-gpu`, что-нибудь меняется?

Answer (score 0):

если кто столкнулся с этой проблемой, 
то откатите версию freetype шрифтов linux